# First Order Logic and undecidability

Tags: first-order-logic

I've read that the resolution procedure (that derives from the Resolution Rule) is complete. So if there exist an empty clause, the procedure finds it.

But , what about **undecidability** ? Does the resolution procedure suffer of it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First Order Logic clauses decidability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680534/first-order-logic-clauses-decidability)

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680534/first-order-logic-clauses-decidability)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it might. If you apply the resolution procedure to a theory that is undecidable, then obviously you'll run into trouble. Even if the theory is axiomatizable, it may simply not be complete, and then of course certain propositions will remain undecidable.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Resolution is a syntactic procedure. What do you mean by "apply the resolution procedure in a model"? Rather than "in a model", do you perhaps mean "to a theory"?

Comment: Well, yes, that would be more accurate. I will edit my answer.